# How to do it can limit the number of open app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I have a program on which you want to limit the number of functions.

For example: send a message function can only be used 10 times, can not be used up in the open, and will pop up the number of your purchase information.

I have tried using the following method can be successful from 10 -> 0, but close the program to reload after the value has changed back to 10 up!!
There is no way 10 -> 0, close the program after re-loading or 0?

Thank you!!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
   numberoftimes = 10;

NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];



[def setInteger:numberoftimes forKey:@"IntegerVal"]; 
[def synchronize];
```

numberoftimes-= 1;

```
 NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


 [def setInteger:numberoftimes forKey:@"IntegerVal"]; 
 [def synchronize];
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are setting the value of `@integerVal` to 10 every time your viewDidLoad method is called. What you want to do is get the existing value before you decrement it...

```
int currentNumberOfTimes = 10;
if ([def valueForKey:@"integerVal"]) {
    currentNumberOfTimes = [[def valueForKey:@"integerVal"] intValue];
} 
numberOfTimes = currentNumberOfTimes --;

[def setInteger:numberoftimes forKey:@"IntegerVal"]; 
[def synchronize];
```